# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, object, typeerror

I can't fix it with the help of the other posts, here is my code:

```
input = input("Tippe ok, um weiter zu machen ")
if input in  ["ok"]:
Spieler1.draw(Deck).draw(Deck)
Spieler2.draw(Deck).draw(Deck)

print("Spieler 1:")
Spieler1.Hand_zeigen()

print("Spieler 1:")
Spieler2.Hand_zeigen

print("Blinds wurden gesetzt. Der Pott beträgt:", Pot)


Einsatz = input("Gebe deine Zahl ein")
```

I have no clue whats going on I only get the message "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: in which line? What are all those unknowns (`Spieler1, Deck, Pot,...`). What are the return values of `draw(Deck)` that you are allowed to chain commands like you do? Not much we can help if half of the code are classes you created and we do not know, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is: you do something like this:

```
class Deck():
    pass

text = "some text"

text().draw(Deck)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    text().draw(Deck)  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this shows you where it happens.
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

From your posted code the most probable culprit would be:

```
Spieler2.draw(Deck).draw(Deck)
```

if `draw(Deck)` returns a string.